# ember.js addon: how to manipulate files?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-addons, ember-addon

We have 5+ `ember.js` projects. I've extracted all common features as an addon. Other projects depend my addon with `package.json` (as npm module).

I want to do some post-processing after my addon upgraded on any project (via `npm install`). I need to do such processing:

- Override `/app/styles.css` file.
- Override `router.js`
- Put some files on `/translations` directory.

Is there any hook to do these? Is there any documentation for hooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we did:

- **Override `/app/styles.css` file:** We are not using app/styles files. We created a bower addon to keep our styles. In our ember addon's `index.js` file, there is a hook called `included(app)`. We use `app.import` calls to place our styles to the apps.
- **Override `router.js`:** We are not overriding `router.js`. Modification needs occur very rarely. So we announce it on our releases if any modification is needed.
- **Put some files on `/translations` directory:** After upgrading `ember-intl#2.8`. We will not need to modify `/translations` directory.

Answer (score 1):

The ([npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#examples)) provides information about the scripts field of package.json. You could use `install` or `postinstall` to run an arbitrary script, which processes your desired changes.